# How to plot relationships in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, social-networking, relationship

The relationship is expressed as a matrix `x` like this:

```
      John Jack Mary Wendy
John     0    2    1     1
Jack     2    0    1     0
Mary     1    1    0     1
Wendy    1    0    1     0
```

The entries refer to the number of connections they have.
Could anyone show me how to plot it as a network in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is known as an adjacency matrix.

There is some information in the R [FAQ](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/STAT/r/faq/snplot.htm) on plotting social networks expressed as matrices:

> Plotting social network data can be easily done with the igraph
>   package in R. [...] In order for the igraph package to recognize this table as a network, we can first convert it to a matrix.  Then, if we wish to calculate graph-related statistics on it (betweenness, closeness, degree), we can use the matrix to create a graph object.

The FAQ gives some examples, resulting in sociogram diagrams, for example:

[image]

The `igraph` library itself is [documented here](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/index.html) - it can produce much more complex examples - see the [screenshots page](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) and the example below:

[image]