# Creating edge list with additional variables in R

Tags: r, edge-list

I have data like this:

```
ID=c(rep("ID1",3), rep("ID2",2), "ID3", rep("ID4",2))
sex=c(rep("male",3), rep("female",2), "female", rep("male",2))
item=c("a","b","c","a","c","a","b","a")

df1 <- data.frame(ID,sex,item)
df1
  ID    sex item
1 ID1   male    a
2 ID1   male    b
3 ID1   male    c
4 ID2 female    a
5 ID2 female    c
6 ID3 female    a
7 ID4   male    b
8 ID4   male    a
```

and I would need it as edges like this:

```
head(nodes)

  ID    sex    V1  V2
1 ID1   male    a  b
2 ID1   male    b  c
3 ID1   male    a  c
4 ID2 female    a  c
5 ID4   male    b  a
```

With @akrun's kind help I could get the V1 and V2 columns with this:

```
lst <- lapply(split(item, DG), function(x) if(length(x) >=2) t(combn(x,2)) else NULL) 
nodes=as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lst[!sapply(lst, is.null)]) )
```

but how could I also "take along" ID and some other variables (sex, age etc) from the original df and have them as "sex" etc columns in "nodes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df1, df1$ID), function(x) {
        m1 <- if(length(x$item)>=2)
          t(combn(as.character(x$item),2)) 
           else NULL
        if(!is.null(m1)) 
       data.frame(ID=unique(x$ID), sex=unique(x$sex), m1)}))
 row.names(res) <- NULL
 res
 #   ID    sex X1 X2
 #1 ID1   male  a  b
 #2 ID1   male  a  c
 #3 ID1   male  b  c
 #4 ID2 female  a  c
 #5 ID4   male  b  a
```

Answer (score 4):

I feel like already solved this once, but here's a possible solution using `data.table` and it's new ([**v >= 1.9.5**](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)) `tstrsplit` function

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(.N > 1) tstrsplit(combn(as.character(item),
              2, paste, collapse = ";"), ";"),
            .(ID, sex)]

#     ID    sex V1 V2
# 1: ID1   male  a  b
# 2: ID1   male  a  c
# 3: ID1   male  b  c
# 4: ID2 female  a  c
# 5: ID4   male  b  a
```

Comment: '@David, yes very similar, but needed the additional variables now. I was thinking of using your previous data.table solution (Thanks for that also!), but did not know how change the code to get the V1 (of the previous solution) to two columns V1 and V2. I'm so new to R, that I'm afraid I'll have to leave learning data.table functions for now...