# How to create edge-list R without duplications

Tags: r, data.table, edge-list

I have a very large dataset which has 3 columns of interest, id, house, & people.  Each id can have multiple houses and each house can have multiple people.  I want to create a edge-list using what @David Arenburg, has shared here [Creating edge list with additional variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449118/creating-edge-list-with-additional-variables-in-r)

However, the issue I have is the edges given are 'a;b' and 'b;a'.  I would like to have them only once.  As large set of a and b could produce thousands of a;b, b;a combinations.

I would like to have them only once as I would like to count how many times the people share a house.

Given the dataset

```
id=c(rep("ID1",3), rep("ID2",6), "ID3", rep("ID4",5))
house=c(rep("house1",2), "house2", rep("house3",2), rep("house4",4), "house5", rep("house6",3), "house7", "house8")
people=c("a","b","c","d","e","d","e","d","e","f","g","h","h","h","h")

df1 <- data.frame(id,house, people)
```

The following code by @David Arenburg gives us the edge-list

```
df1 = setDT(df1)[, if(.N > 1) tstrsplit(combn(as.character(people),
              2, paste, collapse = ";"), ";"),
            .(id, house)]
```

The results

```
     id  house V1 V2
 1: ID1 house1  a  b
 2: ID2 house3  d  e
 3: ID2 house4  d  e
 4: ID2 house4  d  d
 5: ID2 house4  d  e
 6: ID2 house4  e  d
 7: ID2 house4  e  e
 8: ID2 house4  d  e
 9: ID4 house6  g  h
10: ID4 house6  g  h
11: ID4 house6  h  h
```

As you can see there is between V1 & V2, house has both 'd;e', 'e;d' which I would like to avoid. So for large amount of data those combinations could be in 1000s

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more concise base R way, but here's one `dplyr` approach, where we sort the two values to make it easier to eliminate repeats.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(V1s = if_else(V1 < V2, V1, V2),
         V2s = if_else(V1 < V2, V2, V1)) %>%
  distinct(id, house, V1s, V2s)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility following from the excelent answer that @David Aremburg provided.

The overall strategy:

1. Create a new variable with the ordered edge (it is, convert "e -> d" to "d -> e")
2. Get the unique values of each combination of `id`, `house` and the new variable.
3. Drop the variable

.

```
library(data.table)

# keep Aremburg's solution and chain a couple of additional commands:
setDT(df1)[, 
           if(.N > 1) tstrsplit(combn(as.character(people),
                                      2, paste, collapse = ";"), ";"),
            .(id, house)][, 
                         edge := apply(.SD, 
                                       1, 
                                       function(x) paste(sort(c(x[1], 
                                                                x[2])), 
                                                         collapse = ",")), 
                         .SDcols = c("V1", "V2")][, 
                                                  .SD[1, ], 
                                                  by = .(id, house, edge)][
                                    , edge := NULL][]

    id  house V1 V2
1: ID1 house1  a  b
2: ID2 house3  d  e
3: ID2 house4  d  e
4: ID2 house4  d  d
5: ID2 house4  e  e
6: ID4 house6  g  h
7: ID4 house6  h  h
```

Notice that you could drop the rows in which `V1 == V2` too, as those are irrelevant edges. That could be accomplished with `[V1 != V2, ]` at the end of the previous chain.